# How to populate missing observations (N/As) in columns from different data frames with some elegant and efficient code in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, populate

### Problem and goal

There are three R data frames which have the same structure, but are set 
at three different time frequencies (quarter "_q", semi-annual "_sa" and year "_y"). The goal is to populate only the missing observations (N/As) for each variable (column) in the data frame at the quarterly frequency ("data_q"), with those available at the semi-annual ("data_sa") and yearly ("data_y") data frames.

### The original data frames are

```
data_q <-data.frame(date=as.Date(c('2010-03-31','2010-06-30','2010-09-30','2010-12-31','2011-03-31','2011-06-30','2011-09-30','2011-12-31','2012-03-31','2012-06-30','2012-09-30','2012-12-31')),
                cost_q=c('20','N/A','4','7','9','43','N/A','2','5','N/A','N/A','N/A'),
                rate_q=c('500','N/A','600','50','830','260','N/A','560','800','N/A','N/A','N/A'));

data_sa <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c('2010-06-30','2010-12-31','2011-06-30','2011-12-31','2012-06-30','2012-12-31')),
                  cost_sa=c('100','N/A','N/A','N/A','100','N/A'),
                  rate_sa=c('1000','N/A','N/A','N/A','1000','N/A'));
data_y <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c('2010-12-31','2011-12-31','2012-12-31')),
                 cost_y=c('100','100','100'),
                 rate_y=c('1000','1000','1000'));
```

### The desired output is as follows

```
data_q_desired <-data.frame(date=as.Date(c('2010-03-31','2010-06-30','2010-09-30','2010-12-31','2011-03-31','2011-06-30','2011-09-30','2011-12-31','2012-03-31','2012-06-30','2012-09-30','2012-12-31')),
                        cost_q=c('20','100','4','7','9','43','N/A','2','5','100','N/A','100'),
                        rate_q=c('500','1000','600','50','830','260','N/A','560','800','1000','N/A','1000'));
```

### Question

How to populate missing observations (N/As) in columns from different data frames with some elegant and efficient code in R?

Comment: A real missing value would be `NA` and not a string `"N/A"`

Comment: My initial reaction is to suggest just merging them (based on year-quarter and year, respectively) and to use some `ifelse`-magic. I suspect that this is not `elegant and efficient` enough?

Answer (score 0):

I have search/replaced the "N/A" with NA. The lapply part is necessary because you have coded numbers as characters ('500').

```
library(data.table)

df = as.data.table(
  Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(data_q, data_sa, data_y)))

mynames = c("cost_q",  "rate_q",  "cost_sa", "rate_sa", "cost_y",  "rate_y" )
df[, (mynames) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = mynames]

df[,  `:=` (
  cost_qx = ifelse(is.na(cost_q), pmax(cost_sa, cost_y, na.rm = T), cost_q),
  rate_qx = ifelse(is.na(rate_q), pmax(rate_sa, rate_y, na.rm = T), rate_q) 
)]
```